# GWT mvn gwt:debug throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, maven, gwt

When I run my application using `mvn gwt:debug` (or run) from command line, GWT console is opened. When it is ready, I copy URL and open via browser. But sometimes, after some time GWT console hangs, then throws `OutOfMemoryError` (in command line `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`). Only thing I can do is to close the console. It happens randomly - right after opening in browser or after few seconds/minutes/etc. (usually when performing actions).

Problem might be, that I load a big amount of data into memory when application starts. But it hangs after the data is loaded. I searched through Internet, tried to change Java and Maven XMX (tried even ridiculous values, like 4GB), but still no luck. Funny thing is, that for one of my colleagues in the same project it works great (and he has his XMX set to something like 300MB), rest of the team has the same problem like I do. But we are not able to find, what are our configuration differences. From the project point of view, we use the same configuration.

I know, that GWT is horrible if it comes to performance stuff. Any ideas?

**SOLVED**

I added argument, as @ThomasBroyer suggested. Works great now! In my case it was PermGenSpace problem, so I needed to add

```
-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="--XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're tuning the memory of the GWT DevMode process, not the Maven process. Use [`extraJvmArgs`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/debug-mojo.html#extraJvmArgs) (or `-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xmx4g"` on the command-line) to pass JVM args to the forked process.

Comment: Yes: 4g! Don't hesitate with the memory. All the examples I came across somehow convinced me 1024m would be enough. If your GWT Development Mode keeps crashing just slap 4g there! Worked for me, thanks! :P